# CurrentIndex of ComboBox from QML to C++ code

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qml

I would like to get the `currentIndex` of a `ComboBox` in QML.

How can I get that?

From C++, I tried to have a `Q_INVOKABLE` function to call from QML code when `onCurrentIndexChanged` but it seems I can only pass `QObject*` as parameters in these functions in QML. So, it seems I can not pass just a `int`, or I get the error

```
"Could not convert argument 0 at"
...
"Passing incompatible arguments to C++ functions from JavaScript is dangerous and deprecated."
"This will throw a JavaScript TypeError in future releases of Qt!"
```

I tried to look in internet, but I did not find anything straighforward. I can not believe there is no trivial way to get the `currentIndex` from the C++ code. Maybe I am using QML in a wrong way.

A link to some example would also be appreciate.
The ComboBox model is defined in C++ and it is a `QList<MyObject>` but `MyObject` is **NOT** a `QObject`.

Comment: you'll probably have to provide [mcve], now it's unclear exactly what you mean.

Comment: It is not true that Q_INVOKABLE functions can only take QObject* parameters. There's nothing special you need to do to use ints. Show us your code and we can tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: can you share your code  snippet so we can help you

Comment: It's better to connect `onCurrentIndexChanged` to a slot on the *C++* side rather than doing this.

Comment: Hi guys, yes sorry for not posting a clear example. Anyway I solved using slots rather than Q_INVOKABLE. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of solving this. One is to register a handler class and call a slot every time you change the current index.

Example handler class:

```
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class ComboBoxHandler: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public slots:
    void onItemChanged(int newValue) {
        qDebug() << "Value: " << newValue;
    }
};
```

Register it with the engine in your main.cpp

```
qmlRegisterType<ComboBoxHandler>("ComboBoxHandler", 1, 0, "ComboBoxHandler");
```

Use it in your QML file:

```
ComboBoxHandler {
    id: handler
}

ComboBox {
     textRole: "text"
     valueRole: "value"

     // When an item is selected, update the backend.
     onActivated: handler.onItemChanged(currentIndex)

     model: [
         { value: Qt.NoModifier, text: qsTr("No modifier") },
         { value: Qt.ShiftModifier, text: qsTr("Shift") },
         { value: Qt.ControlModifier, text: qsTr("Control") }
     ]
}
```

This is also partly the example code provided in the QML help: [ComboBox docu](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-combobox.html#details)

For more insiged and other solutions, start here: [Integrate QML with C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-cppintegration-overview.html#:%7E:text=QML%20is%20designed%20to%20be,be%20invoked%20directly%20from%20QML.)

Comment: Even simpler, you could have declared `Q_PROPERTY(int index MEMBER m_index NOTIFY indexChanged)` and later declare both `signal void indexChanged();` and `int m_index;` Then, in QML you could just property bind `ComboBoxHandler { index: comboBox.currentIndex }`.

Comment: Hi Stephen, that is exactly the first solution I tried, but it did not work...I don't know why, quite new to QML maybe I did something wrong

Comment: Thanks, I solved the issue. I was using a "Q_INVOKABLE" function (don't ask me why, I worked on a code not written by me), and it was not working. Changing the Q_INVOKABLE for a simple slot worked well.